# PDO returns connectionOptions

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Good afternoon.

I was querying to my database when i got a strange response from DB.

```
C:\wamp64\www\testecat\index.php:24:
object(CatManager)[1]
  private 'connection' (MyDataAcessPDOBase) => 
    object(PDO)[2]
  private 'connectionOptions' (MyDataAcessPDOBase) => 
    array (size=2)
      3 => int 2
      1002 => string 'SET NAMES 'UTF8'' (length=16)
```

i don't know why this happened. i just queried to get all rows from db.I got a manager to connect to it.

```
public function getAllCat(){
        try{
            return $this->getRecords(self::SQL_TABLE_NAME);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            throw $ex;
        }
    }
```

and

```
protected function getRecords($table, Array $where = null, Array $order = null) {

    try {
        $sql = MyDataAccessPDOSQLFactory::buildSQL(self::SELECT_OPERATION, 
                $table, $where, $order);
        $q = $this->prepareStatement($sql, $where);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        throw $e;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw $e;
    }

    $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
    return $q->fetchAll();
}
```

getRecords is a prepared function to connect to DB.

it's not code problem because i use this to other tables and is just fine.

even if do a simple sql query like

```
SELECT * FROM cattable
```

i get the same result.

i don't know why i am getting this. i don't get any errors though.

table is InnoDB, latin_swedish_ci and is an foreign key from another table.

thank you for your time

Comment: You should read http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: ok thank you, i'll read that.
edit: ok i know we can add the charset option, but then why all other table work just fine and this won't?